# How to align and anchor SwiftUI horizontal list at right edge of view?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I am looking for how to align items in a list horizontally, where the items start at the last item, or on the right edge, and go left from there.

For example, with a list of 1-20, I'd be looking to show items 1-5 off the left edge of the screen, with item 20 being the right-most item, right on the edge of the screen. An image of this can be shown below (it is not the solution running, but rather a contrived image to show the desired effect).

[image]

How can I do this in SwiftUI?

An HStack will simply center itself horizontally. HStack doesn't seem to have a horizontal alignment that I can control.

An HStack in a scrollview allows me to reach the right-most item, but still starts at the first item, or the left-most edge of the list.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            // the HStack just tries to fit everything within the width of the view,
            // without anything going "offscreen"
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(1..<21) { index in
                    Text("\(index)")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Divider()
            // placing the HStack within a ScrollView does allow elements to go offscreen,
            // but the list starts at 1 and goes offscreen at 16  on the right
            // I am looking for how to "anchor" the list on the right edge instead,
            // with elements 1 through 5 being displayed off the left edge of the screen,
            // and the right-most element being 20, directly on the right edge of the screen
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(1..<21) { index in
                        Text("\(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 100)
            Divider()
            // are there any other ways to achieve my desired effect?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I properly understand question looks like you need [ScrollViewReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader):

```
// Define array for your label
var entries = Array(0...20)
    
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
   ScrollViewReader { reader in
      HStack(spacing: 10) {
         ForEach(entries, id: \.self) { index in
            Text("\(index)")
         }.onAppear {
            // Here on appear scroll go to last element
            reader.scrollTo(entries.count - 1)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will mark your response as the answer, as it addresses the question. However, I wanted to ask (if you felt inclined to answer, no worries if not), would there a way to do this without a scroll view, and to do it for a "static" HStack?

Comment: You are welcome! 
Probably you can play with this modifier https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/layoutpriority(_:)

Comment: @silentfilozofer e.g. you can set higher `layoutpriority(_:)` accordingly to the index of `ForEach`. I haven't tested it but seems it should works if you'll set higher priority for every next element and in this case, the last one will fit, and the firsts one will be collapsed.